# ORM for google cloud datastore

Tags: python, orm, google-cloud-datastore

https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/overview

It looks like datastore in GAE but without ORM (object relation model). 
May I used the same ORM model as datastore on GAE for Cloud Datastore? 
or Is there any ORM support can be found for Cloud Datastore?

Comment: Not an orm but this might be usefull: https://github.com/transceptor-technology/dbWrapper

Comment: https://github.com/lucemia/google-cloud-datastore-orm an orm approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google Cloud Datastore](https://developers.google.com/datastore) only provides a low-level API ([proto](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta1/proto) and [json](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta1/)) to send datastore RPCs.

[NDB](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/) and similar higher level libraries could be adapted to use a lower level wrapper like [googledatastore](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googledatastore) ([reference](https://googledatastore.readthedocs.org/en/latest/googledatastore.html#id1)) instead of `google.appengine.datastore.datastore_rpc`

Comment: Thanks, Is there any project for that already? (I don't mind if I need to create it myself, I just want to know before I start :)

Comment: @lucemia not that I know of.

Comment: @lucemia you could also consider contributing your changes directly to ndb: https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/wiki/Contributing

Comment: @lucemia do you have an open source repo where you're working on the ndb implementation?

Comment: Someone, who managed to use cloud datastore with NDB, please supply some hint!

Comment: I face some truoble while trying the `datastore_rpc` approach, thus I create a datastore_stub. https://github.com/lucemia/google-cloud-datastore-orm

Answer (score 4):

App Engine Datastore high level APIs, both first party (db, ndb) and third party (objectify, slim3), are built on top of low level APIs:

- [datastore_rpc](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py) for Python
- [DatastoreService](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService.java)/[AsyncDatastoreService](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/AsyncDatastoreService.java) for Java

Replacing the App Engine specific versions of these interfaces/classes to work on top of The [Google Cloud Datastore](https://developers.google.com/datastore) API will allow you to use these high level APIs outside of App Engine.

The high level API code itself should not have to change (much).

Answer (score 3):

For the .NET folks out there, I just created pogo, which is a .NET ORM that supports saving POCOs to Google Cloud Datastore, and querying them using LINQ.

It is available on nuget, called "pogo", and the source is hosted here - http://code.thecodeprose.com/pogo

For example, here's an insert and a lookup:

```
var unique = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

var poco = new TestDepartment
{
    Id = unique,
    Code = 123,
    Director = new TestEmployee { FirstName = "Boss" }
};

using (var session = _datastore.OpenSession())
{
    session.Store(poco);
    session.SaveChanges();
    var lookupPoco = session.Load<TestDepartment>(unique).SingleOrDefault();

    Assert.AreEqual("Boss", lookupPoco.Director.FirstName);
}
```

and here's a query:

```
using (var session = _datastore.OpenSession())
{
    var results = session.Query<TestEmployee>()
          .Where(t => t.HourlyRate > 50.0)
          .ToList();

    Assert.IsTrue(results.Count > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact answer and We already know Google is working for [NDB Library](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/2#issuecomment-24477687), I couldn't wait for that.

What I tried is to write NDB Properties not listed in `datastore_v1_pb2.py`, such as `GeoPt`.

```
class GCDFoo(ndb.Model):
    latlng = ndb.GeoPtProperty()
```

in this case, if we read the entity by GCD lowlevel API, returns like following.

```
name: "latlng"
value {
  entity_value {
    property {
      name: "x"
      value {
        double_value: 10.0
        indexed: false
      }
    }
    property {
      name: "y"
      value {
        double_value: 10.0
        indexed: false
      }
    }
  }
  meaning: 9
}
```

hm, I don't really know what does 'meaning' mean, but It was important to describe GeoPt.
and now We can write GeoPt property something like this.

```
def make_geopt_value(lat,lng):
  entity = datastore.Entity()
  prop = entity.property.add()
  datastore.helper.set_property(prop,'x',lng,indexed=False)
  prop = entity.property.add()
  datastore.helper.set_property(prop,'y',lat,indexed=False)
  value = datastore.Value()
  datastore.helper.set_value(value,entity)
  value.meaning = 9
  return value
```

It worked for me, still don't know if it's right approach though. Anyway I hope my answer is helpful for someone who can't wait NDB Library.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look on this one, this one is written in Typescript

Description: ts-datastore-orm targets to provide a strong typed and structural ORM feature for Datastore (Firestore in Datastore mode).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-datastore-orm

```js
import {BaseEntity, Batcher, Column, datastoreOrm, Entity, Transaction, DatastoreOrmDatastoreError, DatastoreOrmError} from "ts-datastore-orm";

@Entity({namespace: "testing", kind: "user", compositeIndexes: [{id: "desc"}, {string: "asc", ["object.name"]: "asc", __ancestor__: false}]})
export class User extends BaseEntity {
    @Column({generateId: true})
    public id: number = 0;

    @Column()
    public date: Date = new Date();

    @Column({index: true})
    public string: string = "";

    @Column()
    public number: number = 10;

    @Column()
    public buffer: Buffer = Buffer.alloc(1);

    @Column()
    public array: number[] = [];

    @Column({excludeFromIndexes: ["object.name"]})
    public object: any = {};

    @Column()
    public undefined: undefined = undefined;

    @Column()
    public null: null = null;
}


async function queryExamples() {
    const [user1, requestResponse1] = await User.query().runOnce();
    const [userList1, requestResponse2] = await User.findMany([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    const [userList2, requestResponse3] = await User.findMany({ancestor: user1, ids: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]});
    const [userList3, requestResponse4] = await User.query().run();

    const user2 = User.create({id: 1});
    const query = TaskGroup.query()
        .filter("number", "=", 10)
        .filterAny("anyColumn.name", ">", 5)
        .setAncestor(user2)
        .groupByAny("anyColumn.name")
        .orderAny("anyColumn.name", {descending: true})
        .offset(5)
        .limit(10);

    while (query.hasNextPage()) {
        const [entities] = await query.run();
    }

    // stream
    const stream = query.runStream()
        .on("data", (entity) => {
            //
        })
        .on("info", (info) => {
            //
        })
        .on("error", (error) => {
            //
        })
        .on("end", () => {
            //
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Not only can you use the same ORM models, Google Cloud Datastore allows you to read and write from your current App Engine apps storage.

https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/activate?hl=en#google_cloud_datastore_for_an_existing_app_engine_application

Comment: please provider more details. I only saw the instruction about how to connect cloud datastore on app engine. Nothing about the ORM.

Comment: ORM as in the features a layer like ndb provides?