# how to access Google Cloud Datastore through JDO, JPA or Objectify?

Tags: jpa, jdo, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using [Google Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs)  and I'm ok with it, but I have faced with an issue: is it possible to access Google Cloud Datastore (not **GAE**) through JDO, JPA or Objectify?

If yes, how to authenticate and connect them?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642012/orm-for-google-cloud-datastore   Google like to provide derivatives of existing datastores all with very similar names, and this is seemingly a derivative of "Datastore", so will not have JDO, JPA or anything convenient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cloud Datastore API does not currently provide client libraries that support JDO, JPA, or Objectify. However, we are working on porting the App Engine Java client library to work on the Cloud Datastore API, and that should enable JDO/JPA/Objectify as well.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/issues/34